Does Groovy allow trailing comma in lists?
Does Groovy syntax allow trailing commas in lists? I.e.:
def my_list = ["apple", "banana", "telephone",]


isn't it harder to try THIS out before asking?

@injecteer not if my only known way of testing this is in a jenkins instance.

everyone uses smth like https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com to try things out

Thanks, I'm on an air-gapped network unfortunately.

Per the list literal examples in the documentation, yes it does:
assert list == [5, 6, 9, 8,]           // trailing comma OK

